# Бегущая/мигающая строка в C#

Tags: c#, строки

Вообщем, здравствуйте. В проекте C# хочу сделать бегущую/мигающую строчку на форме, возможно ли это? Если да, то помогите совсем еще новичку в C#... Буду очень признателен! :)

Answer (score 2):

Быстро набросал:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        start = label1.ForeColor;
        end = Color.White;
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 500;
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    Color start;
    Color end;

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (label1.ForeColor == start) label1.ForeColor = end;
        else label1.ForeColor = start;
        if (label1.Left > -label1.Width) label1.Left -= 5;
        else label1.Left = this.Width;//this - относительно чего label будет двигаться влево
    }
```

Comment: Я совсем дурачек, да? :с
http://data2.floomby.com/files/share/3_8_2013/1CkWE7Xw0K9LEhNgHZSTg.png

Comment: Исправь на:

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer Audio;
            Audio = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.cherry2);
            Audio.Load();
            Audio.PlayLooping();
            start = label1.ForeColor;
            end = Color.White;
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 500;
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();
        }

Comment: Смотри :(((
http://data2.floomby.com/files/share/3_8_2013/E8qB7cickbgFDdkHSyBA.png

Comment: @bAcup
попробуй уже разобраться, как все строчки взаимосвязаны, и как их заставть делать то, что ты хочешь :)

вон смотри, студия изо всех сил пытается тебе помочь - пишет, что не существуют `start`, `end` и `timer_Tick`, а в коде от @GenkaOk они есть. так что объяви их там где-нибудь

Comment: Перед private Form1_Load добавь Color start, end;

Comment: @bAcup: Если честно, вы бы сначала выучили базовый синтаксис языка, а потом сетовали, что вам написали правильный ответ, но не вставили в вашу программу. Стыдитесь.

Comment: Стыжусь. Сделаю так, как Вы сказали. Извиняюсь.